# c# How to read file with space and other characters like /

Tags: c#, file.readalllines

I have a filer with name Names.txt
and with following data

```
David One And Two/Three 
Alex One Two Four And Five/Six 
Amanda Two Seven/Ten 
Micheal Seven/Nine
```

And here is my code:

```
 string[] Name = File.ReadAllLines("Names.txt", Encoding.Default);
```

and I want to return every row as a string I mean

```
"David One And Two/Three" as one string
"Alex One Two Four And Five/Six" as one string 
"Amanda Two Seven/Ten" as one string 
"Micheal Seven/Nine" as one string ..
```

I mean When I run

```
for(int i = 0; i < Name.Length, i++)
{
    Consol.WriteLine(Name[i]);
}
```

and output should be

```
David One And Two/Three
Alex One Two Four And Five/Six
Amanda Two Seven/Ten
Micheal Seven/Nine
```

But what I get is

```
David One 
Alex  
Amanda Two 
Micheal
```

and Consol.WriteLine(Name.Length) should be 4 but I get 6 I don't know why. Even if the file is empty I get Name.Length 6

I mean like if it was like this

```
string[] Name = {"David One And Two/Three", "Alex One Two Four And Five/Six", "Amanda Two Seven/Ten", "Micheal Seven/Nine"};
```

Please help me what is I'am doing wrong? I tried in Console and windowsForm but the same problem

Comment: What form are the line-endings in the file?  lf or crlf?

Comment: Why not split by '\n' or even use File.Readlines

Comment: @mybirthname It's not every line has '\' I have more lines without \ but with spaces...

Comment: Maybe try using `File.ReadAllLines("Names.txt");` without specifying the encoding?

Comment: Can you try `Encoding.UTF8` instead of `Encoding.Default`.

Comment: **"Even if the file is empty I get Name.Length 6"**. Are you reading from the correct file? Try the full path.

Comment: Copy/Paste your actual code instead of retyping it in here. I'm saying that because there is no way your ForLoop actually compiles the way it's currently written in here. If we see your real code, maybe we'll point the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Copy/Pasted your code, fixed the typos and gave the File.ReadAllLines a full file path. Works fine.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] Name = File.ReadAllLines("M:\\StackOverflowQuestionsAndAnswers\\40472088\\data.txt", Encoding.Default);
        for (int i = 0; i < Name.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Name[i]);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Console Output

```
David One And Two/Three
Alex One Two Four And Five/Six
Amanda Two Seven/Ten
Micheal Seven/Nine
```

To complete my comment about your ForLoop, here is how you have it typed in your problem description:

```
for(int i = 0; i < Name.Length, i++)
{
    Consol.WriteLine(Name[i]);
}
```

It should be more like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Name.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Name[i]);
}
```

Help us help you... Copy/Paste your code.

Comment: Thanks for the -1 with no comment to back it up.